# css3 show div with transition

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab that when I hover over it, I open a dropdown-menu. What I would like is that when I hover over the tab, the dropdown menu will show with an transition of 0.5s to give that animation look.

To be open from top to bottom. Something similar you can see in dropdown on linkedIn page.

This is what I have so far.

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

```
.dropdown-menu {
    width: 211px;
    border-color: #efefef;
    border-width: 3px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 0;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I try add this into the dropdown:hover and dropdown-menu without success.

```
     -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
     transition: opacity 0.5s;
```

Comment: The `transition: opacity` makes a change in the `opacity` property be animated. I however don't see a `opacity` property in your `.dropdown-menu` class. Try adding a `opacity: 0` to `.dropdown-menu` and `opacity: 1` to `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu`. The `transition` should be added to `.dropdown-menu` if you want it to transition from and to the hover state. Not sure if it works while also changing `display: none` to `display: block` though.

Comment: Doing that does not work. And if I change the order and I put the opacity 0 in the hover and 1 into the dropdown-menu when I go to the dropdown it show me the dropdown-menu and disppear. I want the other way around. I

Comment: Animating from top to bottom can only be done by setting a fixed height and using `transition: height`

Comment: can you give me an answer with my code and how it would looks like please

Comment: Not using your code, but this might tell you what properties to look for and give you a start: http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/VLLgrm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add opacity: 0; to .dropdown and opacity: 1; to .dropdown-menu

[Here is a demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/lzxos3qi)

Comment: when I go to the dropdown it show me the dropdown-menu and disppear. I want the other way around.

Comment: The demo that you prove it does not work. put the transition to 3s. it´s doing instantaneously as I had

Comment: OK remove display: none; and display: block;     It seems those do not animate.   You can replace with visibility: hidden; and visibility: visible instead if you want.

Comment: Here is an example (also with moving it downwards) [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/5viqh4lq)